# What is the best way to perform operations for pairs of complete observations in R?

Tags: r, combinations

Consider two vectors `x` and `y` of equal length; each of them have both NA and non-NA values. The objective is to efficiently find pairs of non-NA values between the two vectors to perform some downstream operations on these pairs of complete observations. A complete pair is defined as a non-NA value for index `i` in both `x` and `y`.

What I have tried is the following:

```
complete.pairs <- !is.na(x) & !is.na(y)
complete.x <- x[complete.pairs]
complete.y <- y[complete.pairs]
```

However, I'm unsure if this is the fastest way to do it. For some context, the idea is to process all combinations of rows in a matrix this way (so `x` and `y` would be a single combination). I'm looking for something like what `cor(x, use = "complete.pairwise.obs")` does as it seems highly efficient for finding complete pairs per combination of vectors and then computing a correlation. Here I don't necessarily want to compute a correlation after but rather other things such as statistical tests for example. From my tests, my approach seems really inefficient for large matrices.

Comment: If `dat` is a frame or matrix, then `dat[complete.cases(date),]` will return a subset of `dat` with no `NA` values. Is that what you mean?

Comment: what, is that an r built in function?

Comment: ok I checked it, its sort of along the lines of what I want, but I need the observations that are non-NAs AND that are also not NAs in the other vector

Comment: Yes. if `x` is a vector of (some-`NA`) numbers, and `y` is a different vector (some-`NA`, same or different locations), then `dat <- cbind(x, y)`, then `dat[complete.cases(dat),]` will return all rows where *neither* is `NA`. (In this case, `dat` is a matrix.)

Comment: nice, I managed to implement it  in my work and it sped up things compared to the approach I originally posted.